# C# .net 6 Always get 502 Bad Gateway after deployed but on local is work find?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, .net-6.0

I'm a new at C# .net 6, I have edited the startup.cs and program.cs When I test the system on local it works fine. But when I deployed and test on the server, I always get a 502 Bad Gateway, I wanted to know if there was something I couldn't live without. Or how to check if this error is caused by where the code is wrong? or example startup.cs that work. I really didn't know and I've been stuck here for a long time. Please suggest me, thank you.

I tried to fix startup.cs, but nothing works, always getting 502 Bad Gateway on server.

Comment: What project is it? Web Project?

Comment: It about API Project

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows. You can go to EventViewer to see the logs.
Open Start Menu and type EventViewer, open it and go to
EventViewer -> Windows Logs -> Applications.
and see the logs there.

If you are using another OS then search the web for the equivalent to event log or server log for your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Its is a Web Project then the below code might causing the issue.

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

as, it might be looking for Development Environment. When you deploy, it will no longer be a Development Server. Try removing this and try.